# combine two fields and increment the resualt by 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, full-text-search, increment

I am working on a query that will combine two field (4 numbers) numbers and then search in another column (6 digits)  to find a number that start with the above mentioned combined digits (4 digits) , and then search among these for the one who have the hightest to digit , give it back and increase it by 1,

example :

> Num1  Num2    Combined                                                              > 11     22      112233                                                                                 > 11     22      112234                                                                                 > 22     34      223425 
>   11     22      1122xx

xx should be 35 , so combined number should be 112235
the NUM1 and NUM2 are avilable , Combined coulmn is being updated manually for now , and i need to change this 
any ideas .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want a query that Concats the Num1 and Num2 colums and then search in a 3rd Column where they are combined:

```
DECLARE @FirstFour Int = CONCAT(Num1, Num2)
SELECT TOP(1) Combined + 1
FROM Table Where Combined Like @FirstFour% 
Order Desc;
```

This will select the highest combined number after searching combined column with a concatenated string/number. Now when you return it to your page as a number just add 1 to it and you're good to go.

Edit: Visibility is better now and you could turn the returned value in a variable then add 1 to it and return it to the client/page/application

Edit2: This should work

Comment: Thanks @DieVeenman , that is  a good start point i can  use to start , i was lost about  the syntax , but now i got the clue :)

Comment: Try using the above SQL and tell me if it works or not :)

Comment: unfortunately , it haven't work , this is the query :                                                                               'DECLARE @FirstFour Int = CONCAT( T0.[U_prodcode], T0.[U_typecode])
SELECT TOP(1)  T0.[U_compcode] + 1
FROM AIQG Where  T0.[U_compcode]  Like '@FirstFour%%'
 order by  T0.[U_compcode] Desc'

Comment: it shows this error : it show the following error                                                                                        Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "T0.U_prodcode" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "T0.U_typecode" could not be bound.